# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error when Using Dropbox API

Tags: jquery, dropbox

I'm trying to use a Dropbox API, specifically one that allows a team administrator to take action for the team member, but I keep getting an access-control-error.

Here's my code:

```js
 $(document.body).on('click', '.viewfolders', function() {
    var teamMember = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    //JSONinputs = {"list": "true"};
    jQuery.ajax( {
        url: 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: {
            'X-Dropbox-Perform-As-Team-Member': + teamMember,
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
        },
        beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");                
        },
        success: function(rootresult) {               
           alert('success');
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert('error ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
    
});
```

Here's the error I get:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Any ideas on what's going on here?  Have tried using JSONP as a dataType and gotten a 401 authorization error.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Not using localhost or any domain, just have the HTML files on my desktop

Comment: Also here is the walkthrough of what Dropbox's API requires: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/business#member-file-access

Comment: Are you sure that API is supposed to work client-side?

Comment: At present, I'm working two APIs into my entire script.  The first API does work client-side (it's a Team Member Listing API)

It's when I start trying to do team-member actions that I find an issue.  Find it odd that one works but the other doesn't

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/204324385-Access-Control-Allow-Origin-Issue-using-Core-API-via-DfB-Team-API ]

Comment: This should be fixed now.